# SH script to copy the lastast version

Tags: deployment, jenkins, sh

I need to create a script to copy the latest version of .war file to the Tomcat folder.

For ex., if in the folder, there are two files with name `projectName-0.0.1-SNAPSHOPT.war` and `projectName-0.0.2-SNAPSHOPT.war`, then i would need a script to copy the `version 0.0.2`. Obviously, if a new version `0.0.3` gets created, the script should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command:

```
cp $(ls -1 <path_to_war_files>/projectName-*-SNAPSHOPT.war | sort -V | tail -1) destination_dir
```

Notice that it is `ls -1` (number 1 and not letter l)